# How to configure Autosys Extended calendar to run for first 14 days in every quarter

Tags: schedule, autosys

I have tried with Jan MNTHD#1.... |Jan MNTHD#14|Apr MNTHD#1... so on, but autosys has date condition limitation for 255 chars. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autosys [CYCLE](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/content/broadcom/techdocs/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/ca-workload-automation-ixp/11-3-5/using/manage-calendars.html#concept.dita_8fce7c52b42fa44bc260bbaaf7925d3c1cc82455_ManageCycles) and [EXTENDED CALENDAR](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/content/broadcom/techdocs/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/ca-workload-automation-ixp/11-3-5/using/manage-calendars.html#concept.dita_8fce7c52b42fa44bc260bbaaf7925d3c1cc82455_ManagingExtendedCalendars) can he helpful here.

Step 1: Create a CYCLE, to define a range.

```
cycle: YEARLY_QUARTER
start_date: 01/01/1972
end_date: 01/14/1972
start_date: 04/01/1972
end_date: 04/14/1972
start_date: 07/01/1972
end_date: 07/14/1972
start_date: 10/01/1972
end_date: 10/14/1972
```

Note: To set the cycle to repeat every year, omit the year or select the year "1972"

Step 2: Create an extended calendar based on this cycle.

```
extended_calendar: FIRST_14_QUARTER
workday: 
non_workday:
holiday: S
holcal:
cyccal: YEARLY_QUARTER
adjust:
condition: CYCLE
```

This will include all the days of the cycle and run each day irrespective of holiday or non working day.

Also, you can increase the range of the cycle and then change the condition of the extended calendar accordingly.

Good Luck.

Comment: Could you please help me to create config which run 5th day of every Quarter ?

Comment: update the cycle start_date and end_date as 01/05/1972 and 01/05/1972 resp

Comment: does insert_job allow me to specify date_condition and start_times along with run_calendar in which I would give referance to my extended_calendar ? My altimate goal is to run a job on every quarter at 1 am.

Comment: yes .. you are correct, all the three options would be necessary ..
• date_condition is a boolean value 0 or 1 • start_times - job start time • extended_calendar - your quarter defined Calander

Comment: We have developed Jil script with calendar and cycle but calender is considering dd/mm/yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy. Now I wanted to update dates in cycle, do you know the Jil syntax for updating existing cycle ?